# How to upgrade to Python 3.3?

Tags: python, installation, upgrade

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and wish to use Python 3.3 rather than 2.7 which is currently installed. I downloaded python from python's ftp and installed it. I followed the steps given in : 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-to-install-python-3-3

Now I have Python 3.3 installed in /opt/python3.3 and create sym links for it as told in this URL. Still python --version command tells me that my current version is 2.7.3.

What's wrong?

Comment: Replacing the `python` command with a 3.x binary is an easy way to break a lot of programs, so be glad it didn't do that ;-)

Comment: The answer that you linked to with the installation instructions specifically says that "the whole point is *not* to replace the default interpreter - if you do that, then every python app ran from your account will use Python 3.3, including Ubuntu apps, such as Software Centre ect. We don't want that."

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `python` in terminal use `python3.3`

Comment: Can't I remove the old version?

Comment: It's better to use `python3` than `python3.3`, except when you specifically need 3.3 (e.g., because you don't expect your code to run in 3.4). See PEP 394.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.x and 2.x are incompatible languages.

[PEP 394 — The "python" Command on Unix-Like Systems](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) contains recommendations for how to handle this fact. The short version is this:

- `python` should refer to the latest Python 2.x.
- `python3` should always refer to the latest Python 3.x.
- `python2` should refer to the latest Python 2.x (and *must* if `python` refers to 3.x), but often doesn't.
- `pythonX.Y` should always refer to Python X.Y.

So, running `python3` or `python3.3` should run your custom 3.3 installation, but `python` should run your platform's standard 2.7.

The Rationale and Migration Notes sections explain why the first rule is as it is, but the short version is this: There are millions of scripts out there—some integral to the functional of various OS distros or third-party packages—that assume `/usr/bin/env python` runs Python 2.x, and no scripts that assume it runs Python 3.x.

So, your best bet is to leave things the way your distro wanted, and explicitly use `python3` to refer to your 3.3 installation. (And, likewise, `pip3`, `ipython3`, `idle3`, etc.)

---

The specific instructions you followed also create a link named `py`. This is definitely non-standard, but I can see how it would be convenient. If you want to do this, go for it—then, instead of running `python`, just run `py`.

(However, you still want to make sure you get links named `python3.3` and `python3` onto the path, so you have a PEP-394-compliant installation. If those instructions don't do that for you, do it manually after you're done.)